# Design of Serializing classes

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I just learned how to `serialize` and `deserialize` `objects` to `XML` in `C#`.
Now I would like to add this functionality to my application, I have a `class` for the `object`.  Should I create a `class` that contains the `serialize` and `deserialize` methods? Or, should there be an `Interface` or something?

How is this normally done?

Comment: Look into data annotations and so that you can create POCO's for [de]serialization rather than writing your own serialization methods or implementing ISerializable.

Comment: I would use `Extension methods` as [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/wojan/archive/2011/05/18/145422.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to serialize/deserialize simple classes to XML and back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356976/how-to-serialize-deserialize-simple-classes-to-xml-and-back)

Answer (score 0):

You would be best keeping your object and serialisation mechanism seperate [DataContractSerializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) are good for this in .Net. They allow data annotations (as mentioned in the comment above) to be specified on properties and automate the actual serialisation for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interface (ISerializable), but you also have generic classes that exist and can do the job for you. In that cas you'd have to place the right Attributes for the propertyies you want get serialized.

take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) if you want the documentation about this.

.Net has some built-in serializers (BinaryFormatter and XmlSerializer

if you go with the interface you'll have to write your own methods

Answer (score 0):

Provided your classes are simple enough for serialization you can do this:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Create(filename)){
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRootClassHere));
 serializer .Serialize(stream, yourRootInstance);
}
```

You may need to take a look at XmlElement, XmlAttribute, XmlIgnore, XmlText attributes to control the output better:

```
 [XmlIgnore]
 public bool IgnoredBool{ get; set; }

 [XmlAttribute("NewXmlName")]
 public string RenamedProperty{ get; set; }
```

This should get you going for the most part.